# Errors when we put a service in different js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my two controllers in a separate js file which has a dependency with a service called messages

In app.js file I have 2 controllers

```
var learnModule = angular.module('myApp', []);
learnModule.controller('ListCtrl', function (messages) {
    this.messages = messages.list;
});

learnModule.controller('PostCtrl', function (messages) {
    this.addMessage = function (message) {
        messages.add(message);
    }
});
```

In Services.js I have my service

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('messages', function () {
    var messages = {};
    messages.list = [];
    messages.add = function (message) {
        messages.list.push({ id: messages.list.length, text: message });
    }
    return messages;
});
```

In the `<head>` Part of my template file I have registered the two js files like below

```
  <script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js" runat="server" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/Services.js" runat="server" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/app.js" runat="server" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Note::If i copy the service in my controller js file(i.e app.js) the application works fine..

Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 4):

The issue is, you have two modules with the same name `myApp`. Simply rename the second module,

```
var myApp = angular.module('mySecondApp', []);    
myApp.factory('messages', function () {
    var messages = {};
    messages.list = [];
    messages.add = function (message) {
        messages.list.push({ id: messages.list.length, text: message });
    }
    return messages;
});
```

add it as a dependency to first and you are good to go.

```
var learnModule = angular.module('myApp', ['mySecondApp']);
learnModule.controller('ListCtrl', function (messages) {
    this.messages = messages.list;
});

learnModule.controller('PostCtrl', function (messages) {
    this.addMessage = function (message) {
        messages.add(message);
    }
});
```

Cheers!

Comment: No, keep that intact, because as you said, its the 'entry point' of your angularjs application. However, whenever you write, `angular.module('appName')`, you are essentially registering an app with angularjs. According to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module), if you create a module with a name that already exists, it will overwrite the previous one. (So last-in-wins.)

Answer (score 1):

The call to `angular.module` function has 2 different functions

- if it has a second argument with an array, it attempts to creat a new module (with the names of other modules it depends on listed in the array)
- if it doesn't have a second argument, it attempts to access an already existing module

If there is already a module with that name and you try to create one, or there isn't one created and you try to access it, there will be an error.

The solution would be to only call the function with an array as the second argument once, `angular.module('myApp', [])`, and at the top of the first file referenced in the page. In the others use the the form without a second argument `angular.module('myApp')` to access the module created earlier.

Answer (score 0):

you are re-declaring myApp again.Try naming your service js a new name and add it as a dependency to main module